# Instagram feed extension for M2

Tags: magento2, instagram

Hello and thank you in advance.

Which **instagram** feed extension works best for an M2 store.  Pls suggest if you are using any.

Comment: are you looking for a free extension or a paid one?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below extensions. this extension is free.

https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/instagram-widget-magento-2/

https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-social-feed.html

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-instagram.html

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-instagram-feed

Answer (score 0):

you can buy the below extensions as per your Requirement.

**1.** https://amasty.com/instagram-feed-for-magento-2.html
**2.** https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-instagram-feed/
**3.** https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-instagram.html#
**4.** https://www.milople.com/magento-2-instagram-feed.html